# How to set terminus font as default in Arch linux

Tags: arch-linux, fonts, fontconfig

I am using dwm, no desktop environment package installed. I love using Terminus font in the terminal. Can I set my default font as Terminus, so that gui applications gets it automatically.

I tried changing `/etc/fonts/fonts.conf`, but failed.

Any help appreciated, Thank you!

Comment: hi, any one out there to help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way you can force all your GUI applications to use a specific font by setting it globally. You need to change this from the settings of your specific application. For example, I currently use falkon browser to type this message. I go to **Preferences** -> **Fonts**, and I can set the fonts I need there.

Comment: thank you, I wonder why arch linux have font config files and related.

Comment: Because most applications need and really use it. It ensures that configuration of fonts for all applications can be centralized in one place. Centralizing font configuration will simplify and regularize font installation and customization. The intent is to permit applications to pick and choose appropriate functionality instead of forcing them. Most Qt-based applications e.g use fontconfig.

Comment: It would help if you mention an example of an application which you are facing a problem with and let's see if we can help

Comment: Brave Browser, I would like to have vector fonts.

Comment: @jerry: This is different than your original question. Setting terminus font in applications is different than setting vector fonts.

Comment: @jerry: By the way, it's better if you care to follow-up with your questions by commenting or accepting the answer if correct (even if it is not the answer you wished).

Comment: I appropriate your suggestion, do u have any idea how to set vector font.

Comment: @jerry: do you really mean vector? vector fonts are definitely supported, all .ttf/otf fonts are vectors (not bitmaps), or do mean variable fonts? variable fonts has very limited support currently, I suggest you open a new question and mention an example of the font and the application and some one would help you and close this for now. Thanks for accepting the answer.